# How can two identical no-PIE binaries run simultaneously?

Tags: memory

As I understood it (probably incorrectly) when a no-[PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) binary gets loaded into memory it always has the same *absolute* base address.

This doesn't make sense to me. Consider the exact same program compiled twice with PIE disabled:

```
gcc -no-pie foo.c -o foo1
gcc -no-pie foo.c -o foo2
```

`readelf -Wl foo<1,2>` says both binaries have the same entry point.
Why doesn't their memory overlap then when running them at the same time?

Comment: What does this question have to do with security?

Comment: Not directly, but I came across it during exploit development for a binary exploit. Posting this in stack overflow doesn't make sense as it's not really about software development. I think this stack exchange fits best although I admit not at first sight. Please leave the question up. I think it will benefit others

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> ... it always has the same absolute base address.

No. Each process is provided by the OS with its own mapping of parts of the systems memory. The addresses in a non-PIE binary are not absolute to the system memory but absolute to the process memory.

Comment: @AlexanderHaas See [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: In theory, this would prevent you from dynamically linking two identical copies of a shared library built without PIE, since that would create a shared process address space.

Comment: Why would that create shared process address space?

Comment: @MooingDuck Loading a dynamic library implies bringing its sections into the shared address space of the process that's loading it, so that symbols in that library can be accessed by the main binary, other libraries loaded in the same process, etc. If two non-PIE libraries have overlapping ranges of the address space, and the operating system is unable to remap/relocate one of them, they cannot coexist due to a conflict for that shared memory space.

Comment: @nanofarad why would there simply not be an additional layer of virtualization on the inner process?

Comment: @fectin Because there isn't something to virtualize. The addresses refer to the same memory space, and a virtualization layer isn't going to disambiguate whether 0x400001234 refers to 0x1234 into a DLL loaded at 0x40000000 or 0x234 into a conflicting DLL loaded at 0x40001000. The closest plausible thing to "virtualization" would be relocating one of the two DLLs, which I've already addressed. If anything, "virtualization" typically goes the *other* way, e.g. WoW32 uses separate addresses to load 32 bit and 64 bit libs and shim/jump between them

Comment: At first I thought you were saying two separate processes couldn't dynamically link the same non-PIE library. Now that I've reread everything, you're 100% right. A single process can't link two identical copies of the same shared library, since they would both try to load into the same virtual memory address for that process.

Comment: I don't think typical tools on Linux will let you build a shared library that can't be reliablly loaded. Depending on the architecture they will either include relocation fixups or insist that you build your code with -fPIC.